# Is there any Part-Of-Speech tagger in C#?

Tags: c#, nlp, text-mining, part-of-speech

My data pre-processing for data clustering needs **part of speech (POS)** tagging. I am wondering if there's some library in C# ready for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## SharpNLP

The best tool for natural language processing implemented in c# is [SharpNLP](http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/).

SharpNLP is a C# port of the Java OpenNLP tools, plus additional code to facilitate natural language processing.

## Embedding IronPython and NLTK

Python provides a package [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) (Natural Language Toolkit) used widely by many computational linguists, NLP researchers.

One can try to embed [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) under C# and run NLTK from there.

You can check the following [link](http://blog.samibadawi.com/2010/03/open-source-nlp-in-c-35-using-nltk.html) on how to do it.